# Leon is not able to prove correctness of Simple Recursive program?

Tags: leon

I have tried following programs in Leon

```
object Test10 {

     def sum(n: Int): Int = ({ 
        require(n >= 0)
        if (n == 0) 0
        else    sum(n-1)+1
    })ensuring(res => res==n )    

}
```

Result--Successful

```
object Test10 {

     def sum(n: Int): Int = ({ 
        require(n >= 0)
        if (n == 0) 0
        else    sum(n-1)+n
    })ensuring(res => res==n*(n+1)/2 )

 }
```

Result--Failed(Not terminated)

Am I making any mistake,why the system is not able to produce?Can anyone guide me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second program is actually not `valid`. Ths postcondition is not correct for big values of `n` due to overflows. When the sum overflows, the formula will no longer hold.

You can try to replace `Int` by `BigInt`, it might work. The problem is also difficult due to non-linear arithmetic.

Leon is not terminating because it is looking for a counter-example (as the program is not `valid`) and has to unroll the formula until it reaches the overflow. Of course it would be better to just find the counter-example and report it, but this is a limitation due to the algorithm used in Leon.

Note that your first program is `valid` because there is never an overflow.